# NoClassDefFoundError When launching from terminal(Java)

Tags: java, compilation, terminal, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: start (wrong name: Start)` when trying to run my program from the terminal. I have two classes in my program called `Load.java` and `Start.java` when the files compile fine using `javac *.java` but when I then try and launch `Start.java` using `java Start` I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: start (wrong name: Start)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I have found other examples of people getting similar errors but cant seem to find the solution to mine or why it is happening. So that is my question, why am i getting this error? What can I do to prevent it from happening again?

Thanks, Ciaran.

Comment: It seems like you are running `java start` instead of `java Start`.

Comment: Both give the same result.

Comment: What packages are your classes in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the fully qualified class name. if your class Start is in package `a`, then you must launch using `java a.Start` for example. You can also use the -`cp` option to set Classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the CMD from the main path and run the java command with full package details.

Ex: If your Start.class is in C:\EampleProj\com\test\Start.class. then you should try

C:\EampleProj>java com.test.Start